# JPA Entity life cycle method

Tags: java, jpa

I am new to JPA.Why are JPA entity life cycle methods not allowed to

1.throw checked Exception

2.access Entity Manager

3.cant be final and static.

Comment: You should have found the answer in the document that mentioned these.

Answer (score 0):

When you say life cycle methods that mean those methods will be called by some container and its life management will be done by the containers itself, programmer need not to bother about it this it should not be disturbed  and left intact, having said this what I mean is signature of life cycles methods is never changed, it can just be overridden to provide the implementation. Thus you can't throw checked exception, it cant be final and static. Hope this helps.